# Unexpected end of JSON input and can't find why

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have some difficulty to find why i get an error on my js file when i want to my ajax return : JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)

I have a php file which retrieve these datas :

```
 [{Duree: "01:00:00"}, {Duree: "00:30:00"}, {Duree: "01:00:00"}, {Duree:"00:30:00"},…]
0:{Duree: "01:00:00"}
    Duree:"01:00:00"
1:{Duree: "00:30:00"}
```

I can't find why my json has an unexpected end.
This is my php file :
It use some query filters and then loop trough my set of objects and next add each object's duration to my array and json_encode it.

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../../Reglage/ConnexionBDD.php';
$Query="SELECT DISTINCT Intervention.IDIntervention,DateFin,Remarque,Intervention.IDAgent,DateDebut,IDTypeTravaux,IDVacation as Vacation, IDEtat as Etat,DateDebut,Duree,DescriptionTache 
FROM intervention 
JOIN interventionmaincourante ON interventionmaincourante.IDIntervention = intervention.IDIntervention 
JOIN participerintervention ON Intervention.IDIntervention=participerintervention.IDIntervention 
JOIN faire_la_vacation ON participerintervention.IDAgent = faire_la_vacation.IDAgent
WHERE DateVacation = intervention.DateDebut  ";//base de la requete
//SOME SQL FILTERS WHICH ADD CLAUSE IN PRINCIPAL QUERY
//MANY SQL FILTERS
$messagesParPage=100;
$sql = "Select count(*) as NB from Intervention";
$rep = $bdd->query($sql);
$total = $rep->fetch();
$total = $total['NB'];
$nombreDePages=ceil($total/$messagesParPage);

if(intval($_POST['CurrentPage']) != 0) {
    if(isset($_POST['CurrentPage'])) {
    $pageActuelle=intval($_POST['CurrentPage']);
    if($pageActuelle>$nombreDePages) { // Si la valeur de $pageActuelle (le numéro de la page) est plus grande que $nombreDePages...
        $pageActuelle=$nombreDePages;
    }
}
else { // Sinon
    $pageActuelle=1; // La page actuelle est la n°1
}
    $premiereEntree=($pageActuelle-1)*$messagesParPage; // On calcul la première entrée à lire
    $Query .= " order by DateDebut DESC, IDIntervention DESC, Vacation LIMIT ". $premiereEntree . "," . $messagesParPage;
}
else {
    $Query .= " order by DateDebut DESC, IDIntervention DESC, Vacation";
}

$currentID = "";
$lastID = "";
$rep = $bdd->query($Query);
$total = array();
$tot = array();
foreach($rep as $Intervention) {
    $idVacation = 0;
    switch ($_POST['Vacation']) {
        case 'Matin' :
            $idVacation = 1;
            break;
        case 'Apres-Midi':
            $idVacation = 2;
            break;
        case 'Nuit':
            $idVacation = 3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    if ($Intervention['Vacation'] == $idVacation) {
        $Query = 'SELECT Duree FROM fairegammeoperatoire WHERE IDIntervention=:id';
        $rep = $bdd->prepare($Query);
        $custom = $Intervention['IDIntervention'];
        $rep->bindParam(':id',$custom);
        $rep->execute();
        $Duree = $rep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;
        array_push($total,$Duree);
    }
}
echo json_encode($total);
```

My JS code :

```
tot = '';
var xhr1 = getXhr();
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr1.readyState == 4 && xhr1.status == 200){
        Selection = xhr.responseText;
        for(let i = 0; i < Selection.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                start = Selection[i];
            }
            if ((i + 1) < Selection.length) {
                end = Selection[i + 1];
                tot = addTimes(start, end);
                console.log(tot);
            }
            start = tot;
        }

        alert(tot);
    }
};
xhr1.open('POST','maincourante/Ajax/AjaxCalculGammeOperatoire.php',true);
xhr1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr1.send(Send);
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of an __exact__ JSON your code creates? :-) (From JavaScript, so we can see what is returned to your frontend)

Comment: You already encoded the result of the PHP as JSON so you dont need to `JSON.parse()` it in the Javascript. That will cause an error!

Comment: I don't understand sorry exact json from JS ? after parsed the ajax's return ? or before ?

Comment: I do that every time, json_encode in my ajax php file and in JS file i retrieve the result by using JSON.parse and it's work xD

Comment: You DONT NEED TO PARSE returned data as it is already JSON

Comment: It might help, if you showed us the javascript as well

Comment: Ok i follow your advice and no error on JSON =) thx

Comment: Now I have the function AddTimes who returning (return hours.toString() + ':' + minutes.toString();)

Comment: I want to do the sum of each duration i get on json and alert(result)...